# Having trouble appending javascript into my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, console.log

OK,so I am trying to pull some data from an api. The problem that I have run into is that I am able to find out the information that I am looking for, but am having trouble getting that information out of the console and onto my main index.html page.

Here is my JS code

```
var form = $('#search');
var input = $('#search-keyword');
var results = $('#results');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").on('click', function() {
    var symbol = $("#search-keyword").val();
    $.getJSON("http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/quote/jsonp?symbol=" + symbol + "&callback=?", function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id="search">
  <h1>API Test</h1>
  <input type="search" id="search-keyword">
  <button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

By doing this, I am able to get pretty much what I am looking for. However I cannot get the data from the console to the actual page.

I have tried appendChild

```
var bob = document.getElementById(results);
var content = document.createTextNode(info);
bob.appendChild(info);
```

I have tried innerHTML

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById(results);
theDiv.innerHTML += info;
```

..and I have tried .append()

```
$('#myBtn').click(function() {
  $(results).append(info) 
})
```

I'm out of ideas. I realize that I probably have a small problem somewhere else that I am not seeing that is probably the root of this.  Much thanks to anyone who can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"results"` needs to be in quotes with regular javascript and for jquery you have already decalred the results variable.

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("results");
theDiv.innerHTML += info; 

$('#myBtn').click(function(){
  results.append(info) 
})
```

Also since you are declaring results outside of your document ready call you have to make sure you html comes before the javascript.

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I knew it was something minor, just didn't know what it was. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var form = $('#search');
var input = $('#search-keyword');
var results = $('#results');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").on('click', function() {
    var symbol = $("#search-keyword").val();
    var resultedData = $.getJSON("http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/quote/jsonp?symbol=" + symbol + "&callback=?", function(info) {
        return info;
    });

    var resultDiv = document.getElementById("results");
    resultDiv.innerHTML += resultedData;
  });
});
</script>
```